# Google Cloud Function deployment failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Google Cloud Platform, and I am trying Google Cloud Functions but it is showing really strange behavior. I'm trying to run the following code:

```
exports.helloPubSub = (event, context) => {
 const pubsubMessage = event.data;  
 console.log(event.data.attributes);
 console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());
};
```

But when I click to create a function, the deployment fails and hardly after trying 8-9 times it gets deployed. The error which it throws is

```
Deployment failure:
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "0bb4aa23414dd82b8643cb2c86b5a55af031b22701fbe364a88ea6e61ad481a4", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "HIT", "hash": "0bb4aa23414dd82b8643cb2c86b5a55af031b22701fbe364a88ea6e61ad481a4", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}
```

**Is it a bug in Google Cloud Platform or am I doing something wrong?** If I am doing something wrong, then I shouldn't be able to deploy it even once.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're having problems deploying functions using the Firebase CLI, don't post to Stack Overflow.  Contact Firebase support directly. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I am not using Firebase CLI for deploying.

Comment: If you're using gcloud, then contact Google Cloud support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the Google Cloud Status, we find that there is an outage with Cloud Function deployment at this time (the time of your post).  I can't seem anything wrong with what you have coded and strongly believe that you are being impacted by the outage.

#### References

- [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/)
- [Cloud Function outage](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/20001)